# Numerical Instability Causes Crash in iOS OpenGL ES 3.0 Vertex Shader, Shader Language Version 300

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vertex-shader, opengl-es-3.0

I am doing a block matrix inversion of a 6x6 matrix, split into a 4x4, 2x4, 4x2 and 2x2 block, but somewhere along the way something goes wrong and attempting to access one of the values causes a crash. I thought I would try using isnan() or isinf() to detect the bad value, but that appears to cause a crash as well.

```
// Pieces of a block matrix inversion:
mat4 invA = inverse(A);
mat2 invD = inverse(D);
mat4 schurA = A - B*invD*C;
mat2 schurD = D - C*invA*B;
mat2x4 upperR = -invA*B*schurD;
mat4x2 lowerL = -invD*C*schurA;

// Set outgoing color for the vertex to yellowish:
v_pColorMarker = vec3(0.90, 1.00, 0.60);

// Does not crash, so it seems I can do a multiply with these matrix values:
vec2 p45 = vec2(0.0);
p45 += lowerL*b0123 + schurD*b45;

float temp = schurD[0][1];

// Checking matrix entry for NaN causes crash ????!!!!
if (isnan(temp))
{
    // Set the vertex color to something I’ll be able to see and detect:
    v_pColorMarker = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

Any ideas? I am not sure how to debug this since the crash is happening in the vertex shader and I do not have a good way to inspect the values inside of the matrix. Is it possible for the value at [0][1] in the matrix to be a non-numeric value of some description that would be different from NaN of INF and would crash both isnan() and isinf()?

Comment: If you debug on the device and take an "OpenGL ES screenshot" (camera icon button in Xcode), and step through the draw call stack, you can inspect OpenGL ES state (bound textures, used programs, enabled attributes, actual uniform values -e.g., modelview matrix).

Comment: Will that let me see local values within the shader though? If I wanted to inspect the value of a matrix, like say schurD, how would I do that?

Comment: I don't know about local variables, but uniforms, I believe yes...

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an unrelated problem, where the "instabilities" were coming from using too many addresses and causing the GPU/compiler to either recycle or lose track of the values in particular addresses. Refactoring the code to be more address efficient cause the instability to go away.